# Need help trying to interpret line integral of a vector field as area.

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

So I was watching some videos on Line-Integrals on Khan Acadamy and when Sal was discussing about Line Integrals of Scalar Functions, Sal mentioned that one can think of a line integral as the **area of a curtain** drawn from your curve to your    function.

To elaborate:

$$ f(x,y) = xy
\\
C: x = \cos{t}, y=\sin{t}\\
0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Now we  can think of $$ \int_C f(x,y) \ ds $$ where $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} $ as the area of a curtain as shown below:

[image]

Now my question is:

If we have a vector field $$ \vec{f}(x,y) = P(x,y) \hat{i} + Q(x,y) \hat{j}$$

and we are taking the line integral to calculate Work Done as:

$$ W  = \int_C \vec{f} . d\vec{r} $$

> Sal said line integrals can be thought of as the area of a curtain along some curve between the xy-plane and some surface z = f(x,y). This new use of the line integral in a vector field seems to have no resemblance to the area of a curtain.

How are the two concepts connected?

Comment: The dot product produces a scalar, so the integrand is equal to $F ds$ for some scalar function $F$ after parameterization. That $F$ is the height of the “curtain.”

Comment: @amd So is it safe to say that the scalar value of $ \vec{f} . d\vec{r} $ can be treated as your $z$ variable and that is the ceiling / top of our curtain?